# How to make a registry entry to HKLM instead of HKCU using wix 3.0?

Tags: c#, wix

i am using Wix Toolset.i need to make a registry entry to HKLM instead of HKCU during installation of my console app.how to do that, anyone have any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You need to set value of 'Root' attribute to "HKLM" in RegistryValue element.
For example:

```
<RegistryValue Root="HKLM" Name="RegistryName" Type="string" Value="XXX" Key="XYZ\ABC" />
```

Comment: We can't just directly 'Root' to HKLM,it will throw an error,we need to add one component for the exe file.this will work m sure.

Answer (score -2):

here is the complete code to add a registry entry component:

*before this,add one line for component ref.to call this component and add WIXUTIL ref to your project.

```
<DirectoryRef Id="TARGETDIR">
<Component Id="RegistryEntries" Guid="PUT YOUR GUID HERE" KeyPath="yes" Win64="yes">
  <RegistryKey Root="HKLM" Key="SOFTWARE\AbC\MYFirstwix" ForceCreateOnInstall="yes" Action="createAndRemoveOnUninstall" Id="RegistryEntries">
    <RegistryValue Name="installed" Value="1" Type="integer" />
    <RegistryValue Name="Path" Value="[INSTALLFOLDER]ConsoleApplication7.exe" Type="string" />
    <util:PermissionEx User="Everyone" GenericRead="yes" Read="yes" GenericWrite="yes" Write="yes" />
  </RegistryKey>
</Component>
</DirectoryRef>
<ComponentGroup Id="ProductComponents" Directory="INSTALLFOLDER" >
```